# can not create icon in sap.m.page

Tags: sapui5

How come I cant create icon in my page? it is only one app and one page but still doesnt work.

```
createContent : function(oController) {
        var app = new sap.m.App();
        var statusPage = sap.m.Page("statusPage",{
            title : "some app",
        });
        statusPage.setIcon("http://www.sap.com/global/ui/images/global/sap-logo.png");
        app.addPage(statusPage);
        return app;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add an icon to the title of the page, you'll need to use the `customHeader` aggregation of the Page control. Assign a Toolbar to it, in the Toolbar, you can add an icon button and the title. Note that the `title` property will not work anymore when using a `customHeader`.

So your control hierarchy will look something like: (controls starting with capital letter, aggregation starting with lower-case letter)

```
Page
    customHeader
        Toolbar
            content
                Button (with icon
                ToolbarSpacer
                Text
                ToolbarSpacer
```

Comment: what about Navcontainer? how can I add header and footer to my page using navcontainer? Thank you @mlenkeit

Comment: @Ryan, you would usually put the Page control inside the NavContainer and navigate between pages. If you need the same header and footer across different pages, you can have a Page control for them and the NavContainer as the content of the page. The pages inside the NavContainer wouldn't need headers or footers then.

Answer (score 1):

The icon on `sap.m.Page` only ever set the NavButton, and has been deprecated. What version are you using? From the current documentation:

```
Deprecated:
Since version 1.20. Deprecated since the MVI theme is removed now. This property only affected the NavButton in that theme.
```

Comment: Thanks @Jorg for your answerI am using 1.26.6
I know it is deprecated but still should work or being replace by some other methods.
In other words, how can I add Icon to my page?

Comment: What kind of icon specifically? favicon?

Comment: Just a simple png icon I need to add

Comment: Yes, but to what? The title of the page? An element on the page? The icon visible in the browser tab? The icon of an app on the devices home screen?

Comment: ok. it will be on the left hand side of the title of the page. That is what I thought setIcon method is for.